# BehaviorSubject subscription with debounce

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have BehaviorSubject property

```
public results$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

Lets'say I have a subscription to this

```
this.results$.subscribe(() => this.find());
```

Subscription in being invoked each time when I press any key on keyboards inside input element. So, to prevent many requests to the server, I added debounceTime()

```
this.results$
   .pipe(debounceTime(500))
   .subscribe(() => this.find());
```

But I need to invoke the first `this.find()` without any debounce, just immediately.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `throttleTime` instead of debounceTime. It propagates the first value and then wait for the specified amount of time.

Also change the `BehaviorSubject` to `Subject`.

public results$ = new Subject();

```
this.results$
   .pipe(
         filter(value => !!value && value.length >= 3),
         throttleTime(500))
   .subscribe(() => this.find());
```

Please read about throttleTime, auditTime and debounceTime here - https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators

Comment: I need BehaviorSubject here because I just put here a part of code..
throttleTime works in a little bit different way

I have an input field

User might keyup buttons without any pause. Then if there is a  pause between typing which is more that 500ms, we should send a request

Also I would add more conditions here

.pipe(
     skipWhile((key) => key.length < 3),
     debounceTime(500),
)


We only should send request to find something when input.length >=3

The main issue here is

User typed 2 symbols, it doesn't search

Comment: User typed the third symbol, it waits 500ms, then searches. I just need to search immediately when it's "3" and then after 500ms pause

Comment: Updated my answer as per your requirement